# How to call a fetch function and pass it an ID parameter on the click of an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an anchor tag with a campus name. I want when the user clicks on the campus name they are directed to a page which will display details of that campus. In order to get the campus details I am using a Jquery fetch. How do I pass a campus ID when the user clicks the anchor tag to the Jquery fetch function?

HTML: `<a id="campusName">' + row.campusName + '</a>`

JQUERY: `fetch('https://Campuses/${id}')     .then(r => r.json())     .then(r => {`

Comment: `fetch()` is not a jQuery method.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: `fetch('https://Campuses/{id}’) `, has mismatching quotes, neither of which are the `\`` character needed for template literals, and your `{id}` should be `${id}` for a template literal

Comment: Do I need to wrap the fetch in a function so I can call it on the onclick of the anchor tag?

Comment: You're going to need an event listener bound to something that will catch the click event of the link.  Weither or not you put the fetch call directly in that listener, or in another method and call that method from the listener, is up to you

Comment: I am new to frontend coding. Can you please give me some code samples? Thank you so much! Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are asking how to add an event listener to an element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: How would I go about storing the campus ID inside the anchor tag but not actually displaying it?

Comment: What do you mean?  `id` attributes, and attributes in general (aside from value in some cases, and placeholder), on elements are not visible to users.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190645/discussion-between-r-p-and-taplar).

Comment: @Taplar when i inspect my html element I see it has an id of 1. When I click on it I see its passing the ID like this (maybe its encrypting it) .        https://Campuses/$%7Bid%7D

Comment: Because you are not using [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) correctly.  You have to use `\`` like I mentioned earlier.